# if statement to count how many no answers? php

Tags: php, variables

Can't seem to find anything on this, though I might just not know what i'm looking for.

I want to check if out of 6 variables, how many of them are yes. So if four return "no" values, then two are yes.

I was thinking to set up an if chain where

```
$var_array = 0;
if ($var1 == "yes"){
  $var_array++;
}
if ($var2 == "yes"){
  $var_array++;
}
```

Then use the array to tell me how many yes values were returned.
Which naturally would work, but would be a long process. Is there an easier way [or more eloquent] to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$vars = array($var1, $var2, $var3, $var4, $var5, $var6);
$yes_count = 0;
foreach($vars as $var) {
  if($var == "yes")
    $yes_count++;
}
```

Comment: If you have consistent variable names that are just indexed by numeral, you could take this one step further and write a loop with index $i, and have something like $varName = $var . $i; if ($$varName == "yes") . . . though if your variable names are that consistent, I'd wonder why you didn't get your input into an array or something more sensible

Comment: You just fixed my next question haha

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for the [`array_keys`](http://php.net/array_keys) function making use of the second, the *search*, parameter:

```
$vars      = array($var1, $var2, $var3, $var4, $var5, $var6);
$yes_count = count(array_keys($vars, 'yes'));
```

Also it's advisable you use an array instead of numbered `$var` variables in the first place.